# My code decompiled a strange format, how do i fix it?

Tags: lua, bytecode, decompiling

I have decompiled and old LUA I had, but when i read it , its not text anymore.

This lua had instructions in JSON about some settings read by my app, but i lost the source code

Ive looked on the internet for solutions and they said maybe its my decompiler version.

My code was compiled with lua(5.1.4) and I used unluac with support to 5.1.x

Could someone help me?

Here is a sample of my lua

```
_G["7S\241\167\161\130\229\224\217J\017]\2204?\172"] = {
  ["\000\014\229\130\208\191%7\224\226Q\145\203\165I\142"] = {
    ["%7\188\003\019s\237\136\155\221\162\015}*QV"] = "\253\020N\161\192\021\238[<\138\020\248\244\171=\138\148\142\230\a\015_D\219CGq\vP\028?&",
    ["tq\204\255\175$l\223\197\219\216\149\248\206:\253"] = "9\128\227#\002\133\216\246\135\238v7\023nO\191",
    ["t\184.\b\030\155Y(\204?dO\131\182\222\129"] = "\001\165\249\154\2184k\a\151\150\028_\025=\173\134",
    ["\169\127\159\172\206\018r3\233\191\160\006\173\\\020\166"] = "\197g{\218\001\"&\169\170|/\233$\190\220T",
    ["\174\006\v9\251\220`^\1280\171\190\r\185\222\238"] = " t\023\019EUw\249\228\028\021N\2359;G",
    ["\197\v\026\171\188\002\233\023\031\132\253\159\223e\249\145"] = "\127\160L6\237Xze\r\194j\1933\255\245w",
    ["\214c\195\207p0\237\198\219D\129\171\243@5\210"] = "f5\001\250\164`\200\231\a\186\1582a\215D\230\026\243\022\146y\226\025\"\248\170\224\016@\240\209\143"
```

Comment: Upload your original code, not the unluac output.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://app.box.com/s/tnajokxdho0dkiiymnnlr536gzr9048e) to both versions of the code (compiled and decompiled) i dont have anymore the source code

Comment: All string lengths are multiple of 16.  This probably means that this implementation of Lua you're using is modified and all the strings are encrypted with some symmetric cryptoalgo.  Strings are automatically decrypted by your Lua when bytecode is loaded.  To know the algorithm you should reverse engineer the host executable.  Or you can just load again this file into your Lua and save your module by some other way (just printing the strings on the screen) instead of saving bytecode to a file.

Comment: Ill try the second first, if not ill deal with the executable